# Getting Unauthorized on Create ChatMessage even though Application has Teamwork.Migrate.All permission (BETA)

Tags: api, graph, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the /beta endpoints for Microsoft Graph API, but I'm getting an Unauthorized error when trying to create chat messages on behalf of other users (or any user).

In v1.0 of the API, the Create chatMessage method is not Supported, but in Beta it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http, as "Teamwork.Migrate.All" permission, which my Application has in Azure.

It is strange, because the same App can create Teams, channels and add members, but not add channel messages.

Anyone know where to look next?

Edit: I got this back now: "You need to add user delegated permissions in your application to at least *Group.ReadWrite.All* in portal.azure.com and then consent as user or Grant admin consent in portal. And re-run *On behalf of a User | Get User Access Token* request to update access token."

However, it does not make sense in regards to what the Beta documentation says about the permission "Teamwork.Migrate.All", which my app has as an "Application Permission": "Allows the app to create chat and channel messages, without a signed in user. The app specifies which user appears as the sender, and can backdate the message to appear as if it was sent long ago. The messages can be sent to any chat or channel in the organization."

If I'm an app and I have that permission, what should I do with a User Access Token? I'm using the App Access Token.

Answer (score 3):

For simply posting message to Teams Channel using `Application Permission` is not supported by Microsoft Graph

Alternatively you can [setup](https://www.sharepointeurope.com/post-message-to-microsoft-teams-using-incoming-webhook/) `Incoming Webhook` which is connector in MsTeams's channel and after finish set up on Teams channel you will received URL which you could use Postman or any API consumer app to send request(your message) to `Incoming Webhook` which will be post in Teams Channel

[Sample Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5X5w.png)

NOTE: `Incoming Webhook` is not support for replying post

Comment: thanks! This is really helpful. I was looking many hours to get this working

Answer (score 2):

> You need to add user delegated permissions in your application to at
> least Group.ReadWrite.All in portal.azure.com and then consent as user
> or Grant admin consent in portal. And re-run On behalf of a User | Get
> User Access Token request to update access token.

It seems that you need to use a user token instead of an application token to create chat messages. The only difference between them is that the user token requires the user to log in. The application token allows the application to create chat messages on behalf of other users. Currently, you can only use user tokens.

As your prompt message says, you need to grant the **Group.ReadWrite.All** `delegation permission` to the application, and then grant the admin consent for the permission, and then you need to use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain the access token.

[image]

---

**Update:**

I think what you are doing is [importing messages](http://I%20think%20what%20you%20are%20doing%20is%20importing%20messages,%20not%20creating%20chat%20messages,%20it%20does%20require%20you%20to%20have%20the%20Teamwork.Migrate.All%20application%20permission.), not creating chat messages, it does require you to have the **Teamwork.Migrate.All** `application permission`.

Importing messages is special, it requires you to create  team and create achannel in the **migration** state, you need to include the `migration` value in the `teamCreationMode` and `channelCreationMode` instance attributes in the POST request. See: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok! So, if I'm building a migration app for moving messages from Slack into Teams - I need this permission for every single user whose messages I'm going to re-create in the new Teams-channels, as part of migrating the channel history?

Comment: @Override  Yes, you need to make each user log in to the application that grants Group.ReadWrite.All permission, and then the application will use the user token to call the API to create a chat message.

Comment: When you say "log in to the application" - what does that mean exactly? What application are we talking about? I'm migrating content for 1000 users, it's gonna be hard to apply manual processes to this..

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean correctly. What you are doing is importing messages instead of creating them?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-2-import-messages-text-only

Comment: @Override  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you :)

Comment: I just tested to create the team in migration mode, and that worked, but I could not specify an owner in a team in migration mode, so I went ahead and created it anyways, and tried to add me as a member (role: owner) afterwards, but that endpoint then gives me an error (Bad Gateway ?!): 

`{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadGateway",
    "message": "Failed to execute backend request.",
  }
}`

Are you not allowed to have team members in a team in migration state? If so, how are you supposed to import messages when you need to tie them to user ids?